# How do you create a state machine within a state?

Tags: c++, state-machine, rhapsody

I want to have a top-level statechart with not-too-many-states. So, normally (i.e. in pure C++) each state can be a state-machine itself. How can I do this in Rhapsody?

e.g.: I have the statechart:

```
*--> init --> do_stuff --> finished
```

When it enters the do_stuff state I want it to drop down into the do_stuff_statechart (which I guess is just another normal class with a statechart):

```
*--> read_config --> check_config --> init_reconfig --> doing_config --> exit
          ^               |
          |               |
          +---------------+
```

When the sub-statechart gets to `exit` it should go back to the top level state chart and enter the finished state...

I can't really see how to do this.. I mean I could just call an event into another state chart and wait for it to respond - but then where is the "diagrammatic" way to link the do_stuff state to the do_stuff_statechart?

Is there an example anywhere of this? Or is there a "pattern" to follow to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Rhapsody, when you right-click a state in a statechart, you should see in the context menu an option called "Create Sub-Statechart".

Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: ah.... and there it is!, yes, that is exactly what I am looking for - thanks Shlomo : )    ... I was starting to think that feature was missing - the tutorials/docs that I can find online don't explain sub statecharts at all : (

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you need a state-machine for the processing of a state in a state-machine, you have two choices:

1. Force the slave state-machine to run to completion before returning to the master state-machines manager.
   This completely abstracts away the fact that you use a slave state-machine from the master state-machine, but reduces transparency, possibly needs more resources, and might have an effect on interruptability.
2. Add some extra state to the state-machine which is handled as opaque by the master state-machine, but will be used by the slave state-machine to handle itself.
   You still have to partition the node into setup, running, and maybe teardown. Aside from that, it needs a bit more dispatching to reach the right sub-state-handler.
3. Flatten the state-space, by substituting the node in the master state-machine with all the nodes of the slave state-machine.
   The only disadvantage is that there is basically no insulation of the slave state-machine from the master state-machine left.

Now, it's yours to decide on what is the best fit for your use-case.

Comment: Ok, so if I understand correctly 1. is like what I was suggesting (just get top state machine to call an event into the sub-statemachine to kick it off, then wait for an event from sub-statemachine to continue...). I don't really understand points 2/3... it appears to be saying (in short) to add extra states at the top level?

Comment: @code_fodder Not quite. Instead of wait for an event, it's wait for that node's processing to end, whatever that entails, like for any other node. Yes, 2 and 3 mean more top-level nodes, be it for managing a slave state-machine, or absorbing it in completely.

Comment: I am not really sure what a processing node is - is that a Rhapsody thing? - but as you say I think option 1 would be better then 2/3 for me. I also still don't understand how you link the top-state-machine with the sub-state-machine in terms of rhapsody navigation... I'll have to look up the processing node terminology : )

Comment: A state-machine is a net of states (nodes) and transitions (edges). Either might be associated with some processing, and transitions may additionally require an event (signal) in order to trigger.

Comment: ah cool - thanks for the translation!, I was going with Rhapsody terms "states", "transitions" and "events".  +1 for the help though shlomo's answer hit the nail on the head for me